# Why I can't compile cpp file using gcc to be 32 bit?

Tags: arch-linux, gcc, c++, 64bit, 32bit

linux 64 bit and while trying to compile my cpp file I receive an error
would appreciate any help, thank you
The gcc command

```
gcc -m32 -g mmn12-q2.cpp -lstdc++
```

The error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../libgcc_s.so.1 when searching for libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../libgcc_s.so.1 when searching for libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 when searching for libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../libgcc_s.so.1 when searching for libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 when searching for libgcc_s.so.1
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Hey guys installing lib32-glibc and lib32-gcc-libs fixed my problem, hope it will help people in the future !

Comment: Please write that as an answer down below, and include the exact steps you took

Answer (score 1):

To compile and link a 32-bit program on 64-bit Arch Linux, you need to `pacman -S` the following packages:

- `lib32-glibc`
- `lib32-gcc-libs`